# MongooseError: Operation `doctors.find()` buffering timed out after 10000ms

Tags: node.js, database, mongodb, express, mongoose

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N7uPn.png) getting this error in my mern project. Sometimes the code work initially but sometimes it show this error. i tried many solutions but it seems not working. but the mongo database is connecting fine but taking some times such as (10-15second).

server.js

```
import mongoose from 'mongoose';
const connectDB = async () => {
    try {
        const conn = await mongoose.connect(process.env.MONGO_URI);
        console.log(`MongoDB Connected: ${conn.connection.host}`);
    } catch (error) {
        console.error(`Error: ${error.message}`);
        process.exit(1);
    }
};

export default connectDB;
```

Comment: Welcome to SO, could you please provide code how is your mongoose connection?

Comment: This error always happens when you are trying to use a mongoose model typically before a connection has been established or you are not using the correct connection for that model. Mongoose lets you start using your models immediately in your code but won't thrown an error if you use them without establishing that connection, hence the timeout error. As stated before by @rick - post your connection and model code for help.

Comment: Hi, the use of images for code/errors causes many problems. Please read [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/7353417).  Thank you

Comment: `import mongoose from 'mongoose';

const connectDB = async () => {
  try {
    const conn = await mongoose.connect(process.env.MONGO_URI);
    console.log(`MongoDB Connected: ${conn.connection.host}`);
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(`Error: ${error.message}`);
    process.exit(1);
  }
};

export default connectDB;`that's my mongo connection. also very slow connection on hot reload.

Answer (score 0):

I can't be sure without seeing more of your code but from your error stack it looks like you are staring your app without waiting for the MongoDB connection to establish (i.e wait for the promise to resolve from the async call);

Import your `server.js` like:

```
import connectDB from "./server.js";
```

Then when you call connectDB start your app once it's been settled in a then block:

```
connectDB().then(() => {
    const port = 5000;
    app.listen(port, () => {
        console.log(`Server Running on port ${port}`);
    });
}).catch(error => {
   // do something with error
   console.log(error);
});
```

or

```
await connectDB();
const port = 5000;
app.listen(port, () => {
    console.log(`Server Running on port ${port}`);
});
```